# Losing data when passing from Rails to Javascript via CRUD fetch request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, fetch

I am trying to log in a user and am able to successfully send the login data from the JavaScript frontend to the Rails backend via a fetch request. I believe I am successfully starting a session in the backend, and am trying to pass the member information back to the front end, but when I look at the response from the json being passed back, it does not include the member info as well. It does return the status: 200, but I cannot find the 'member' data.

Also, what would be the best way to track the member session on the JS side?

Here's my Ruby on Rails session controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    include CurrentMemberConcern

    def create
        @member = Member
        .find_by(email: session_params[:email])
        .try(:authenticate, session_params[:password])

        if @member 
            login!
            render json: {
                status: :created, 
                logged_in: true,
                member: @member 
            }
        else 
            render json: { 
                status: 401,
             errors: ['No such member', 'Verify credentials and try again or sign up']
            }
        end
    end

    def is_logged_in? 
        if logged_in? && current_member
            render json: {
                logged_in: true,
                member: current_member
            }
         else
             render json: {
                 logged_in: false,
                 message: 'no such member'
            }
        end
    end

    def destroy
        # session[:member_id] = nil
       logout!

        render json: { 
            status: 200, 
            logged_out: true 
        }
    end

    def session_params
        params.require(:member).permit(:email, :password)
    end
end
```

My application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token #added because javascript frontend doesn't using js for frontend.  A rails frontend would auto-create this authenticity token. 

    helper_method :login!, :logged_in?, :authorized_member?, :logout!, #current_member (current_member is currently in controller/concerns)

    def login!
        session[:member_id] = @member.id
    end

    def logged_in?
        if @current_member
            render json: {
                logged_in: true, 
                member: @current_member
            }
        else
            render json: {
                logged_in: false
            }
        end
    end


    def authorized_member?
        @member == current_member
    end
end
```

and my JavaScript fetch request:

```
async function submitLogin() {
  
  let email = document.getElementById("login-email").value;
  let password = document.getElementById("login-password").value;
  const memberLogin = { member: { email, password } };

  let options = {
    method: "POST",
    credential: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":
        "file:///Users/awb/Coding/Flatiron/Projects/bookclub-javascript-rails-api/bookclub-frontend-javascript/index.html",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(memberLogin),
  };

  fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", options)
    .then((resp) => {
      resp.json();
    })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      // how do I track the session and find who is logged in on the javascript side?;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try it this way, first:

```
render json: { member: { id: @member.id }, logged_in: true }, status: :created
```

Or you could look into https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json
  
    def create
      ....
      if @member 
        login!      
        respond_with @member, status: :created 
      else
        ...
      end
    end
  end
```

`@member` will be serialized and returned as a JSON. IMO you don't need that `logged_in` because if the status is created and you receive a member back in the response, it's clearly logged in.